# how to add border dynamically such that it does not affact layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a menu bar where I need to show border on hover. but adding border is disturbed the layout.

How can add border without affecting layout.

Comment: Reduce the height by the number of pixels your borders are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two choices.

Probably best is to add a border even when it's not on hover, but set the color to `transparent` (or to the background color). Then in the hover only change the `background-color:`, but not the size or existence of the border.

Or you can use `outline:` - but check browser support for it first.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the  border width, if you are using 1 px border then reduce 2 px from width and 2 px from height for each element for which you are adding border.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outline instead of border property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding outline or manipulating height I change the margin of current hovered element.